# Cookies don't set when using PHP 4.4.7, they do however when using PHP 5.2.9 - Any ideas why?

Tags: php, cookies

So I have been working on a project for a client on their current web site which has been in existence for quite some time.  The version of PHP used is 4.4.7, and I am not in a position to ask them to upgrade.  (The system is old and it could break something)  This past week I made some changes to my project, everything worked fine cookies set, pages worked.  I go to test the site earlier and all of the sudden the cookies no longer work.  After 2 hours of troubleshooting I finally just set up a simple test page composed of this:

```
<?php
setcookie('eventCookie','1', time()+7200,'/','.levijackson.net');
echo $_COOKIE['eventCookie'];
?>
```

I put this on both their site as well as my own (I changed the .levijackson.net to the appropriate domain)

I did 2 refreshes of the page on both pages and only on mine did it return the cookie.  So what could have caused something like this?  Is there a certain setting that may have been changed by their admin/host?

I did test and HttpOnly cookies still work, so I am going to switch to them while I troubleshoot.

edit: Almost forgot to mention, it works fine in FF but in Chrome and IE it doesn't work at all.  Not sure if this will be useful, but I still think that it is not the browser.

Thanks
Levi

Comment: what if you leave off the path and domain parameters?

Comment: Still not working, same results as beforehand.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer.  if it looks like both sites are actually sending the same HTTP headers, try making two test pages: one which sets the cookie and one which reads the cookie.  then be sure to clear cache, cookies, and history, and then restart the browser, between tests.  i also gave you a +1 for actually working with me here (it's amazing to me how often people ask for help on SO but then when you ask for more info, they don't respond).  but i'm going to bed now, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kip, that site helped me out enormously.  As you can read from my comment below the headers helped me solve it.

Comment: maybe the time isn't actually correct on the servers?  Try printing `date('Y-m-d H:i:s O');` on both servers.  if one server's time is off by three hours, telling it to expire the cookies two hours from now will still be in the past (equivalent to unsetting the cookie).

Comment: Yeah, the server with php 4 was 5 hours ahead of the current time, so by setting my cookie to expire in 2 hours it was auto unsetting.  Where as my server with php 5 is in my timezone so setting the cookie to expire in 2 hours worked fine.  I ended up setting the cookie to expire in a day instead of a couple hours.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess-- it could be that their server has [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) enabled, and the file that is being auto-prepended outputs something to the client.  Once *anything* is sent to the client, `set_cookie()` will not work, since cookies have to be set in the page header, which must be sent before anything is sent to the client.

If it's not that, try diff'ing the "PHP Core" section of a `phpinfo()` dump, looking for any other settings that might somehow affect this.

**Edit**: Here's something else you can try, if both sites are publicly accessible.  Go here: http://web-sniffer.net/.  This site will show you the actual HTTP headers which are being returned by the site.  Run the test file for both sites, and look to see if there is any difference in the Set-Cookie headers which are returned.

Comment: phpinfo() says, 'auto_prepend_file no value no value'.  I just ran though the rest and they are all the same.  I also edited above, I don't know if it matters but FF works fine where as Chrome and IE do not.  So perhaps it isn't the php?  I am not sure how a browser could affect how php is processed?

Comment: The only difference I can see between the two headers is with php 4 it is sending 'expires=Wed, 30 Sep 2009 02:16:37' and with php 5 it sends 'expires=Wed, 30-Sep-2009 05:33:37'.  From that I saw that my cookie was expiring as it was created...  So weird, I am going to have to ask about it.  Can you think of a reason the time would have changed?

Anyway, thanks for the help!